# "Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY"

Tags: android

Iam trying to build or create a Android application but Iam seeing the error

"Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY"

Comment: Are you using any library in your project?

Comment: Asthe error suggest, you are missing to use library or its reference

Comment: Do you have google maps? If so, you should create emulator with Google API support

Comment: How to create  emulator with Google API support?

Comment: Yes tried that too  same error when remved use library etc

Answer (score 1):

You use an emulator without the Google APIs but you require them in your project. Change the AVD image to support the Google API and also change your project to be built with the Google APIs.

Comment: How to change the AVD image to support the Google API ?               changing the project to be built with the Google APIs?

Comment: in the AVD manager/project settings under eclipse/gradle build file

Comment: no improvement  tried all       please help still. I selected Galaxy Nexus simulator with all enabled like GPS etc.

Comment: Then check what @CommonsWare said

Answer (score 0):

You have a `<uses-library>` element in your manifest. Either:

- that `<uses-library>` should not be there, or
- you are attempting to install the app on a device that does not have that library